# Code To Crush A Swift Application on Startup/launch

Tags: swift, xcode

In an Xcode project, how can I write any Swift codes that crashes the Application on startup once it’s launched/run on the simulator or device?

Comment: What does crushing an application mean?

Comment: I suppose the author of the question means "to crash".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow app lifecycle events in your [`UIApplicationDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate). For example [`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:))`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application) is called, when the app started and a little time before it's visible. You can put the crashing code there.

There are [a few ways to crash the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511178/easiest-way-to-force-a-crash-in-swift). One of them is to call [`fatalError()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1538698-fatalerror).